# Objects between methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

[image: Screenshot of error]

Is there any way that I can use objects between methods?

Comment: Huh. Did you consider **learning** C and Objective-C? [This...](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/Objective-C-Course-How-To-Use-Objective-C-Instance-Variables)

Comment: You have declared a local variable. You can't use it outside that method's statement block.This is fundamental and the simplest things you must know

Comment: So again I ask: What about this question is “ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical” so that it “cannot be reasonably answered in its current form”?

Comment: This reads like a good question to me. It may be a beginner question, but it's still a good question. If it isn't a duplicate, it should be allowed to be answered.

Comment: "What about this question is... overly broad?" My opinion was that, in its current form, it isn't clear precisely what the user's trying to achieve. There are many potential answers to the question (e.g. declare it as a property, an instance variable, a static variable...), but without the context of the rest of the code it's hard to know which of these is an appropriate answer. Yes, we could edit the question to make it more specific so that a specific answer was warranted, but we don't know if that edit is in line with the original question's intention.

Answer (score 1):

stringOne have to be the member variable of your class:

[EDITED] MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

 CString* stringOne;

}

@end
```

Comment: then what is the proper way to use it? do i just put it after the @implementation??? Isn't that not neat?

Comment: In your header file in @interface block would be fine :)

Comment: Wait, I want to ask another question. Then for example I have a class called "Book". Then if I made and object called "Book1" from that class, where should I put it so that I can call that object from my App Delegate?

Comment: Because if I just put it anywhere behind the @implementation, it will say:"Initializer element not compile time constant"

Comment: With Class Book is exactly like with CString: you do #import "Book.h" in your AppDelegate.h file. Now "knows" the AppDelegate abot Book. So you can declarate "Book* book;" here. Now in your @implementation block (AppDelegate.m) you can do "book = [[Book alloc] init];" or so and use book .

Comment: but then it says "initializer is not a compile time constant"

Comment: @user1927992: You can't have the initializer in the instance variables section; instance variables are always initialized to zero (`nil` for a variable that holds an object pointer). You must initialize the variable in your implementation of `init`.